# visualizing hyperplane equation of SVM

Tags: machine-learning, language-agnostic, svm

I have been trying to understand the SVM algorithm and i can not fully get the hyperplane equation. The equation is- **w**.**x**-b=0. 
What i understand(with lots of confusions) is- **x** is unknown set of all the vectors that constitutes the hyperplane and **w** is normal vector to that hyperplane. We do not know the **w**, we need to find the optimal **w** from training set.

Now, we all know, if two vectors are perpendicular to each other then their dot product is zero. So, if **w** is normal to **x** then that means it should be **w**.**x**=0, but why it's saying **w**.**x**-b=0 or **w**.**x**=b?(normal and perpendicular is same thing, right?) In normal sense, what i understand if **w**.**x**=b, then **w** and **x** is not perpendicular and the angle between them is more or less than 90 degree.

Another thing is, in most tutorials(even MIT professor in his [lecture](https://youtu.be/_PwhiWxHK8o)) it is being said, that **x** is projecting on **w**, but as I know if i want to take projection of **x** onto **w** then it will be **x**.**w**/|**w**| (without the direction of **w**), not only **w**.**x** . Am i right with this point?

I think, i am missing something or misunderstanding something. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

First, to be in line:

- The projection of **x** onto **w** is (**x.w /|w|**²) **w**. And **x. w/|w|** is the component of **x** in the direction of **w** (as **w/|w|** is a unit vector of direction **w**)

Then, you might be confusing two things:

1. If **x** is a vector of an hyperplane, then **x.w** = 0 is the equation of the hyperplane. Unfortunately, we do not want any of your **x** to be on the hyperplane.
2. In the case of SVM, you do not know any vector **x** on the hyperplane. Instead, you have a training set {(**x**1,y1), ..., (**x**N, yN)} from which you want to find the normal vector **w** of the hyperplane (then you can describe any vector **x** of this hyperplane knowing that **w.x** = 0).

---

So let's inspect the second point where you have a dataset {(**x**1,y1), ..., (**x**N, yN)}
and you want to find the hyperplane equation, ie its normal vector **w**, thanks to some particular vectors (called the support vector).

- There is no reason why any of these **xi** should be normal to **w**. Moreover, it's impossible for all **x** to be normal to the hyperplane (If so, let's consider two vectors **x1** != **x2**. Then **w.x1** = 0 = **w.x2** => **w.(x1-x2)** = 0 meaning that either **w = 0** or **x1=x2**)
- But what we want is that **w.U** >= C if **U** positive (one side of the hyperplane) and **w.U** < C if **U** negative (other side of the hyperplane).
- As of a particular **U**, we can choose the vectors in the dataset. We expect them to be at a certain distance D (called the gutter in the lecture) of this hyperplane. So we have **w.x**i >= C + D if yi positive. And **w.x**i < C - D if yi negative
- Let's put b = -C and D = 1 (without loss of generality). Then **w.x**i + b >= 1 if yi positive. **w.x**i + b < -1 if yi negative.
- If multiplied by yi (being equal to 1 if **x**i positive, or -1 otherwise) it leads to yi ( **w.x**i +b ) >= 1.
- Finally, by taking the support vector, ie those defining the gutter, we obtain yi (**w.x**i + b ) - 1 = 0

Comment: What is the difference between projection of x onto w and component of x in the direction of w ?

Comment: Not much. Just that you normalize w so its norm |w| is not taken into account in the projection of x onto w.

Comment: ok, from your first point what i understand, in the equation w.x-b=0, x is not the vectors on the hyperplanes, instead it is vectors from the training set, am I right?

Comment: Why do you want to have **w.x** - b = 0? This equation is somehow equivalent to **w.x** = 0, depending on your notation as explained [here](http://www.svm-tutorial.com/2015/06/svm-understanding-math-part-3/)

Comment: I still do not get your point of "difference between projection of x onto w and component of x in the direction of w ", may be i am dumb enough to, not to get your point, but the link you gave me, that tutorial is also telling he same what i understand about projection. check  [this page](http://www.svm-tutorial.com/2014/11/svm-understanding-math-part-2/). sorry for bothering you.

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer about the projection. Hope it'll help.

Comment: Thanks, so is there any explanation that why they are saying dot product of x and w is projection of x onto w?